# Sorting and ordering varchars in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this SQL table that looks like this

[image]

As you can see the Original Principal Balance is not ordered correctly. These variables are stored as a VARCHAR. How would I sort and order them correctly?

Here is my sql code:

```
WITH Original_Principal_Bal
AS (
    SELECT [New Loan Number]
        ,[Current Amortizing UPB]
        ,[Current Def UPB]
        ,sum([Current Amortizing UPB] + [Current Def UPB]) OVER (PARTITION BY Deal) AS [Total UPB]
        ,BPO
        ,[Current Rate]
        ,[Current Maturity]
        ,[Next Due Date]
        ,[First Payment Date]
        ,CASE 
            WHEN [Original Loan Amount] BETWEEN 0.01
                    AND 100000
                THEN '$0.01 to $100,000'
            WHEN [Original Loan Amount] BETWEEN 100000.01
                    AND 200000
                THEN '$100,000.01 to $200,000'
            WHEN [Original Loan Amount] BETWEEN 200000.01
                    AND 300000
                THEN '$200,000.01 to $300,000'
            WHEN [Original Loan Amount] BETWEEN 300000.01
                    AND 400000
                THEN '$300,000.01 to $400,000'
            WHEN [Original Loan Amount] BETWEEN 400000.01
                    AND 500000
                THEN '$400,000.01 to $500,000'
            WHEN [Original Loan Amount] BETWEEN 500000.01
                    AND 600000
                THEN '$500,000.01 to $600,000'
            WHEN [Original Loan Amount] BETWEEN 600000.01
                    AND 700000
                THEN '$600,000.01 to $700,000'
            WHEN [Original Loan Amount] BETWEEN 700000.01
                    AND 800000
                THEN '$700,000.01 to $800,000'
            WHEN [Original Loan Amount] BETWEEN 800000.01
                    AND 900000
                THEN '$800,000.01 to $900,000'
            WHEN [Original Loan Amount] BETWEEN 900000.01
                    AND 1000000
                THEN '$900,000.01 to $1,000,000'
            WHEN [Original Loan Amount] BETWEEN 1100000.01
                    AND 1200000
                THEN '$1,100,000.01 to $1,200,000'
            WHEN [Original Loan Amount] BETWEEN 1300000.01
                    AND 1400000
                THEN '$1,300,000.01 to $1,400,000'
            WHEN [Original Loan Amount] BETWEEN 1600000.01
                    AND 1700000
                THEN '$1,600,000.01 to $1,700,000'
            WHEN [Original Loan Amount] BETWEEN 1900000.01
                    AND 2000000
                THEN '$1,900,000.01 to $2,000,000'
            WHEN [Original Loan Amount] > 2000000.01
                THEN '$2,000,000 or greater'
            END AS [Original Principal Balance]
    FROM Portfolio_Analytics..Securitization_Tape
    )
SELECT [Original Principal Balance]
    ,COUNT([New Loan Number]) AS [Number of Mortgage Loans]
    ,ROUND(sum([Current Amortizing UPB] + [Current Def UPB]), 0) AS [Aggregate Unpaid Principal Balance as of Cut-off Date ($)]
    ,ROUND(avg([Current Amortizing UPB] + [Current Def UPB]), 0) AS [Average Unpaid Principal Balance ($)]
    ,ROUND(sum(([Current Amortizing UPB] + [Current Def UPB]) / [Total UPB]) * 100, 2) AS [Percetage of Aggregate Principal Balance as of Cut-off Date(%)]
    ,sum(BPO) AS [Aggregate Updated Value($)]
    ,ROUND(sum([Current Rate] * ([Current Amortizing UPB] + [Current Def UPB])) / sum([Current Amortizing UPB] + [Current Def UPB]), 2) AS [Weighted Average Mortgage Interest Rate(%)]
    ,ROUND(sum(([Current Amortizing UPB] + [Current Def UPB]) / bpo * ([Current Amortizing UPB] + [Current Def UPB])) / sum([Current Amortizing UPB] + [Current Def UPB]) * 100, 2) AS [Weighted Average Updated Loan-to-Value Ratio(%)]
    ,ROUND(sum((DATEDIFF(month, [Next Due Date], [Current Maturity]) + 1) * ([Current Amortizing UPB] + [Current Def UPB])) / (sum([Current Amortizing UPB] + [Current Def UPB])), 0) AS [Weighted Average Remaining Term to Maturity(Months)]
    ,ROUND(sum((DATEDIFF(month, [First Payment Date], [Next Due Date]) + 1) * ([Current Amortizing UPB] + [Current Def UPB])) / (sum([Current Amortizing UPB] + [Current Def UPB])), 0) AS [Weighted Average Remaining Term to Maturity(Months)]
FROM Original_Principal_Bal
GROUP BY [Original Principal Balance]
```

Perhaps I need to store the numbers differenly when I create the table, I am not sure how else to match what I want it to look like though.

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: The right answer is of course that you should not use a database table to store human readable *output*, but should have 2 separate *numerical* columns with the lower and upper bound respectively. Rendering does not belong to the database layer, but to the application that runs on that database.

Comment: The person who designed this table should be slapped :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
ORDER BY MIN([Original Loan Amount])
```

You will also need to include `[Original Loan Amount]` in the CTE.

Comment: What does CTE stand for?

Comment: @Snorrlaxxx . . . CTE = "Common Table Expression".  Those are the aliases introduced with `WITH`.

Comment: @Snorrlaxxx . . . I don't believe you.  This is a very effective way to get the ordering that you want.  Is the column stored as a string, by any chance?

Comment: Where do I put the GROUP BY MIN([Original Loan Amount])?

Comment: Msg 144, Level 15, State 1, Line 108
Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @Snorrlaxxx . . . My bad.  I put the wrong keyword in the answer.

Comment: What keyword is it suppose to be??

Comment: @Snorrlaxxx . . . I had `GROUP BY` instead of `ORDER BY`.  I fixed the anwer.

Answer (score 0):

As trincot commented, "rendering" doesn't belong in the database layer. I don't necesarily agree or disagree with this statement. While it may be a "best practice" there are always practical reasons to go against the norm.

Seeing as your bucket labels are manually entered strings, I think the best option would be to simply add a ranking column to your select statement. Something like this:

```
WITH Original_Principal_Bal
AS (
    SELECT [New Loan Number]
        ,[Current Amortizing UPB]
        ,[Current Def UPB]
        ,sum([Current Amortizing UPB] + [Current Def UPB]) OVER (PARTITION BY Deal) AS [Total UPB]
        ,BPO
        ,[Current Rate]
        ,[Current Maturity]
        ,[Next Due Date]
        ,[First Payment Date]
        ,CASE 
            WHEN [Original Loan Amount] BETWEEN 0.01
                    AND 100000
                THEN '$0.01 to $100,000'
            WHEN [Original Loan Amount] BETWEEN 100000.01
                    AND 200000
                THEN '$100,000.01 to $200,000'
            WHEN [Original Loan Amount] BETWEEN 200000.01
                    AND 300000
                THEN '$200,000.01 to $300,000'
            WHEN [Original Loan Amount] BETWEEN 300000.01
                    AND 400000
                THEN '$300,000.01 to $400,000'
            WHEN [Original Loan Amount] BETWEEN 400000.01
                    AND 500000
                THEN '$400,000.01 to $500,000'
            WHEN [Original Loan Amount] BETWEEN 500000.01
                    AND 600000
                THEN '$500,000.01 to $600,000'
            WHEN [Original Loan Amount] BETWEEN 600000.01
                    AND 700000
                THEN '$600,000.01 to $700,000'
            WHEN [Original Loan Amount] BETWEEN 700000.01
                    AND 800000
                THEN '$700,000.01 to $800,000'
            WHEN [Original Loan Amount] BETWEEN 800000.01
                    AND 900000
                THEN '$800,000.01 to $900,000'
            WHEN [Original Loan Amount] BETWEEN 900000.01
                    AND 1000000
                THEN '$900,000.01 to $1,000,000'
            WHEN [Original Loan Amount] BETWEEN 1100000.01
                    AND 1200000
                THEN '$1,100,000.01 to $1,200,000'
            WHEN [Original Loan Amount] BETWEEN 1300000.01
                    AND 1400000
                THEN '$1,300,000.01 to $1,400,000'
            WHEN [Original Loan Amount] BETWEEN 1600000.01
                    AND 1700000
                THEN '$1,600,000.01 to $1,700,000'
            WHEN [Original Loan Amount] BETWEEN 1900000.01
                    AND 2000000
                THEN '$1,900,000.01 to $2,000,000'
            WHEN [Original Loan Amount] > 2000000.01
                THEN '$2,000,000 or greater'
            END AS [Original Principal Balance]

,CASE 
            WHEN [Original Loan Amount] BETWEEN 0.01
                    AND 100000
                THEN 0
            WHEN [Original Loan Amount] BETWEEN 100000.01
                    AND 200000
                THEN 1
            WHEN [Original Loan Amount] BETWEEN 200000.01
                    AND 300000
                THEN 2
            WHEN [Original Loan Amount] BETWEEN 300000.01
                    AND 400000
                THEN 4
            WHEN [Original Loan Amount] BETWEEN 400000.01
                    AND 500000
                THEN 5
            WHEN [Original Loan Amount] BETWEEN 500000.01
                    AND 600000
                THEN 6
            WHEN [Original Loan Amount] BETWEEN 600000.01
                    AND 700000
                THEN 7
            WHEN [Original Loan Amount] BETWEEN 700000.01
                    AND 800000
                THEN 8
            WHEN [Original Loan Amount] BETWEEN 800000.01
                    AND 900000
                THEN 9
            WHEN [Original Loan Amount] BETWEEN 900000.01
                    AND 1000000
                THEN 10
            WHEN [Original Loan Amount] BETWEEN 1100000.01
                    AND 1200000
                THEN 11
            WHEN [Original Loan Amount] BETWEEN 1300000.01
                    AND 1400000
                THEN 12
            WHEN [Original Loan Amount] BETWEEN 1600000.01
                    AND 1700000
                THEN 13
            WHEN [Original Loan Amount] BETWEEN 1900000.01
                    AND 2000000
                THEN 14
            WHEN [Original Loan Amount] > 2000000.01
                THEN 15
            END AS [Balance Rank]

    FROM Portfolio_Analytics..Securitization_Tape
    )
SELECT [Original Principal Balance]
    ,COUNT([New Loan Number]) AS [Number of Mortgage Loans]
    ,ROUND(sum([Current Amortizing UPB] + [Current Def UPB]), 0) AS [Aggregate Unpaid Principal Balance as of Cut-off Date ($)]
    ,ROUND(avg([Current Amortizing UPB] + [Current Def UPB]), 0) AS [Average Unpaid Principal Balance ($)]
    ,ROUND(sum(([Current Amortizing UPB] + [Current Def UPB]) / [Total UPB]) * 100, 2) AS [Percetage of Aggregate Principal Balance as of Cut-off Date(%)]
    ,sum(BPO) AS [Aggregate Updated Value($)]
    ,ROUND(sum([Current Rate] * ([Current Amortizing UPB] + [Current Def UPB])) / sum([Current Amortizing UPB] + [Current Def UPB]), 2) AS [Weighted Average Mortgage Interest Rate(%)]
    ,ROUND(sum(([Current Amortizing UPB] + [Current Def UPB]) / bpo * ([Current Amortizing UPB] + [Current Def UPB])) / sum([Current Amortizing UPB] + [Current Def UPB]) * 100, 2) AS [Weighted Average Updated Loan-to-Value Ratio(%)]
    ,ROUND(sum((DATEDIFF(month, [Next Due Date], [Current Maturity]) + 1) * ([Current Amortizing UPB] + [Current Def UPB])) / (sum([Current Amortizing UPB] + [Current Def UPB])), 0) AS [Weighted Average Remaining Term to Maturity(Months)]
    ,ROUND(sum((DATEDIFF(month, [First Payment Date], [Next Due Date]) + 1) * ([Current Amortizing UPB] + [Current Def UPB])) / (sum([Current Amortizing UPB] + [Current Def UPB])), 0) AS [Weighted Average Remaining Term to Maturity(Months)]
FROM Original_Principal_Bal
GROUP BY [Original Principal Balance]
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
order by cast(substring(left( [Original Principal Balance],charindex(' ',[Original Principal Balance])-1),2,1000) as decimal(18,4))
```

This will convert the first number to a number and sort on that.

Comment: you also need a replace([data],',','') before casting

Answer (score 0):

There's one very cool thing about the MONEY data type... It doesn't complain about commas or currency symbols and it's a numeric data type, so it sorts like and other number... Here are few examples...

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(50) = '$700,000.01 to $800,000';

SELECT CONVERT(MONEY, SUBSTRING(@string, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', @string, 2)));

SELECT CONVERT(MONEY, LEFT(@string, PATINDEX('%[^0-9.,$]%', @string)));

SELECT CONVERT(MONEY, LEFT(@string, CHARINDEX(' ', @string)));
```